# Why does the id type in Objective-C omit the asterisk?

Tags: objective-c

My understanding of the Objective-C `id` type is that it's a pointer to an object of unknown type. In my eyes it's like a void* for Objective-C classes with some compiler sugar on top for stuff like type checking. My question is why is it not `id*` instead of `id` then since it is a pointer type? If this were Java or C# where object references aren't declared using an `*` then I wouldn't be so surprised. But in Objective-C, every class is referenced by C-style pointers, so why hide the `*` for the unknown object type?

Comment: There is no asterisk in `Class` either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `id typedef` is already a pointer:

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

From the [Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW3):

> In Objective-C, object identifiers are of a distinct data type: `id`.
>   This type is the general type for any kind of object regardless of
>   class and can be used for instances of a class and for class objects
>   themselves.
>
> ```
> id anObject;
> ```
>
> For the object-oriented constructs of Objective-C, such
>   as method return values, id replaces int as the default data type.
>   (For strictly C constructs, such as function return values, int
>   remains the default type.)
>
> The keyword nil is defined as a null object, an id with a value of 0.
>   id, nil, and the other basic types of Objective-C are defined in the
>   header file objc/objc.h.
>
> id is defined as pointer to an object data structure:

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

> Every object thus has an isa variable that tells it of what class it is an instance. Since the Class type is itself
>   defined as a pointer:
>
> ```
> typedef struct objc_class *Class;
> ```
>
> the `isa` variable is frequently
>   referred to as the “isa pointer.”